# Adding cells to AddItem based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to add the values of say column B to ComboBox2 if their corresponding cells in a different column match the value of ComboBox1?

If I were to select a customer ID in ComboBox1, I want in ComboBox2 all the invoices related to that customer ID to put in as AddItems.

This is my current prFill for ComboBox1:

```
Private Sub prComboBoxFill()
    TRows = Worksheets("Customers").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    ComboBox1.Clear
    For i = 2 To TRows
        ComboBox1.AddItem Worksheets("Customers").Cells(i, 1).value       
    Next i
End Sub
```

And basically what I want for prFill2 for ComboBox2 is to check which customer ID is selected in ComboBox1, using the prFill above, and then add the cells from column B that have the customer ID selected in prFill in column A. I hope that makes sense.

I can't come up with a way for this to work, I begin to doubt if this is even possible to achieve. So if any of you have any idea, please do let me know.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
After trying some things I figured this might work, however it only adds the corresponding cell of the first row with the same customer ID as the value of ComboBox1. Is there a way to fix that?

```
TRows = Worksheets("Customers").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        For i = 2 To TRows
            If Trim(Worksheets("Customers").Cells(i, 1).value) = Trim(ComboBox1.Text) Then

                ComboBox1.AddItem Worksheets("Customers").Cells(i, 2).value

                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
```

Comment: You can probably do this without writing a single line of VBA code, using data validation, tables, and named ranges. Otherwise, you'll need to check what customer ID is selected in `ComboBox2`, which you're not doing, and then verify the corresponding cell in the `Customers` sheet at row `i` to determine whether or not to add it to `ComboBox1`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I do kind of need the VBA code though, because it's used in a UserForm. I sort of got it working, but I'm still not entirely there yet. I added the code to the main post. It only picks up on the first row that has the same customer ID in it as in ComboBox1, while it should pick up on every row that has said customer ID in it. Would you know a fix to make it so?

Comment: Remove/comment out 'Exit For'